# Keep base app alive when feature crash, when using android aab

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I develop an Android app for Iot, and the App is the only one in system. To update it dynamically I build it with aab. I regard the base app as 'desktop' and dynamic features as 'other apps in system'. To get the best experence, the 'desktop', has to be alive always.

So the question is, How to keep base app alive when crash happened in dynamic feathres?

The best effect I hope is, without restarting, return to the base app, when crash happened in dynamic feathres. It just like the effect in system: apps crashed and go back to desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way. Build Multi-process application.
Define distinct process to use in your manifest
[android:process](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#proc).

> The name of a process where all components of the application should run. Each component can override this default by setting its own process attribute.
> By default, Android creates a process for an application when the first of its components needs to run. All components then run in that process. The name of the default process matches the package name set by the  element.
> By setting this attribute to a process name that's shared with another application, you can arrange for components of both applications to run in the same process — but only if the two applications also share a user ID and are signed with the same certificate.

You can define the process at Application and Component(BroadCastReceiver, Service,Activity, ContentProvider) Level.
But, remember since your feature and base app runs in separate process. so you should IPC to communicate to each other.
Also, static global field and `lock` is no use for this.

Answer (score 2):

The base and feature modules all run in the same process as if they lived in a single APK, so don't search something specific to dynamic delivery to solve your problem, you'll have to use regular coding patterns to catch exceptions at the right places when invoki